Excel, VBA, attach event to ListObject or Chart
I've got some code, that retrieves data from DB, creates a ListObject, and a Chart above.
When i generate a chart, i'm making some ~by hand modification - for example i'm changing individual bar color, using ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format.Fill according to data in ListObject, im also adding some kind of static graph element - lines using series. The problem is when user use Filtering feature on that ListObject. Series get automatically updated, but how can i run my code to change bar color, or redraw / recalculate my static series ?
Can i hook somehow to SeriesChange event in that chart from VBA ?
Or maybe there is a way, to run my code when user change filtering on Listobject ?

The "classic" way to detect a change in filtering is to create a new sheet, in which only a single formula, e.g. =SUBTOTAL(103,Table1[Column1]) is entered and then, in the Calculate event for that (new) sheet, enter the code that you want executed when the filter is changed
